# Probability of 2 Identical Objects Being Placed in the Same Box Out of 3 Identical Boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Imagine we are supposed to distribute 2 identical balls into 3 identical boxes. I would like to find out the probability of both balls being placed into the same box. I can think of two solutions:

1. Place the first ball in any of the three boxes. The probability that the second ball is placed into the same box is $\frac{1}{3}$.
2. List all the possible ways of distributing 2 identical balls into 3 identical boxes and the answer will be the fraction $\frac{\text{number of outcomes with both balls in the same box}}{\text{all the possible outcomes}}$. Doing this I get:

   `2|0|0,  0|2|0,  0|0|2`

   `1|1|0,  1|0|1,  0|1|1`

   which is 6 possible outcomes. The 3 ones in the first row are desired so the answer should be $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$.

As it's obvious I get two different results from above methods ($\frac{1}{3}\ne \frac{1}{2}$). I am fairly certain method 1 is correct, what am I doing wrong in the second one?

Comment: The first method is correct.  The second method incorrectly assumes that the various patterns are equi-probable.

Comment: @lulu which ones are more probable?

Comment: $(2,0,0)$ has probability $\frac 19$.  while $(1,1,0)$ has probability $\frac 29$ since it does not specify which ball goes in box $1$.

Comment: This is just the same as arguing that getting a $2$ out of the toss of two fair dice is half as likely as getting a $3$.

Comment: @lulu It makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: @lulu So can I say when writing out the second row of possible outcomes, I should have counted `1|1|0` twice? Because it represents `A|B|0, B|A|0`.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  If you distinguish the two balls, each distribution is equally likely.  That's why, when working with dice, we often assume that a toss is an ordered pair.  So getting a $(1,2)$ is not the same as getting a $(2,1)$.